# Is `/dev/urandom` secure to generate a salt on a Virtual Machine?

Tags: hash, random

I've read the new `password_hash()` function from PHP uses `/dev/urandom` to generate a secure salt, however this assumes some noise from device drivers.
Is possible that `/dev/urandom` is not so random when in example deploying a website on a Virtual machine? (in example the same image of a operative system snapshot is runned and in reality what we get is just a "hash" of system time?) I am assuming that simulating the operative system is going to be deterministic (or more deterministic than) unlikely a system running on bare metal.

**EDIT:**

Is `/dev/urandom` random enough to allow unpredictable salts to be generated on a Virtual Machine?

Comment: are you asking about the randomness of `urandom` or the suitability of `urandom` for generating salts? Or are you asking how random a salt must be to remain secure?

Comment: I'm asking for suitability of `urandom` for generating salts when running the system on a virtual machine (like many modern hosting services) wich is likely to be runned from a system image

Comment: Then Steffen has your answer

Comment: I'll give the usual 24h interval before accepting to see more answers, possibly by someone who already investigated the issue.

Comment: I just readed virtual machines have entropy problems: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/92224/will-two-virtual-machines-running-on-the-same-physical-host-machine-get-the-same?rq=1

Comment: Related: [Is a rand from /dev/urandom secure for a login key?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/3936/76890)

Comment: Not related, that question is for a regular OS, I'm asking specifically for OS on a virtual machine.

Comment: Not that this is an authoritative source, but read over the following if you want some information about urandom and its security: http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/

Answer (score 4):

The salt in a password  just needs to be random enough so that its more or less evenly distributed. The salt is just used to make attacks with precomputed password hashes or rainbow tables infeasible by increasing the needed memory. Thus there is no need for a cryptographically secure random generator. This means that the implementation is secure enough in your case.

Comment: theoretically, system time in epoch could be a suitable salt?

Comment: In theory nope. Predicatble salts are to be avoided wich made me asking the question

Comment: @DarioOO why are predictable salts to be avoided? And how is time predictable?

Comment: Predictable is not a problem. But the system time has not really a wide range of values (within the specific time frame the code is in use). But a simple pseudo random generator with the time as seed should be sufficient.

Comment: the php wiki specifically says to avoid weak salts, so wich one of the opinions and why?

Comment: @DarioOO: without having any kind of exact reference (there is more than one page in the PHP wiki!) it is impossible to find out what they really mean (i.e. missing context). This means I'm unable to answer your question in the comment properly.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php here search for "Caution It is strongly recommended that you do not generate your own salt for this function. It will create a secure salt automatically for you if you do not specify one. "

Comment: @DarioOO: there is no conflict with my answer. My answer describes what is needed for a secure salt. `/dev/urandom` can be used but a pseudo number generation is sufficient too. But you should not use a fixed salt or a salt generator with an obvious bias or a salt generator with only few possible salts because then you don't get the effect you want from the salt. And that's why it is probably better to use a secure default provided by PHP instead of inventing your own and this is exactly what the statements in the PHP wiki means.

Comment: ok then Good salt need P, but then do `dev/urandom` have P?

Comment: @DarioOO: what kind of P you are talking about? Please add context.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39078/discussion-between-dariooo-and-steffen-ullrich).

Comment: @DarioOO and any future readers, it is worth noting that by **"obvious bias"** this means a *SEVERE* bias. For the purposes of a salt, we just want to choose something that *hopefully* won't repeat between multiple users, thus forcing the attacker to have to try every option for each user with a different salt. If some repetition occurs, this is necessarily horrible, but that would allow an attacker to attempt to crack passwords of multiple users at once. So in practice, a very slight bias (e.g., modulo bias) could be considered permissible for a salt, but very severe biases should be avoided.